# "End of statement expected " string syntax error in python

Tags: python, string

[image]

I have the following variable assignment:

```
xpath_query="xpath='//a[@id="mylink"]'"
```

This is giving me an error in my pycharm editor and giving a syntax error when I run this code. What am I doing wrong?

when I hold the cursor over the red squiggle it says:"end of statement expected "

Comment: Hint: Look at the syntax coloring in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have double quotes inside your " " block. so it becomes:

"xpath='//a[@id=" <-- stick together with --> "]'"

Hence it is a string syntax error.

To include `"` inside `" "` block, you can use `\` to escape the character:

```
xpath_query="xpath='//a[@id=\"mylink\"]'"
```